# Does the supremum of the set $S=\{x\in\mathbb{Q}: x>2\}\subset \mathbb{R}$ exist?

Tags: supremum-and-infimum, rational-numbers

> Does the supremum of the set $S=\{x\in\mathbb{Q}: x>2\}\subset \mathbb{R}$  exist?  If not, prove it.

I don't think the supremum exist, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: If you don't think the supremum exists, try assuming that it does and then deriving a contradiction. (This is a standard first step when you think something can't exist but you don't know why.)

Answer (score 0):

## A supremum does not exist in this set. (With the standard ordering and operations for  $\mathbb{R}$)

Proof:

1. Suppose a Supremum exists, call it M.
2. M+1>M and  $M+1\in\mathbb{Q}: x>2$

Therefore M was not the supernum

If an unnatural order relation exists, then you could make it so that there is a supernum as you could define that 42>x for all other x in R (the hitchhiker's guide metric), then since 42>43 in this case the proof is invalid. But in this case you're really just defining the order relation to have a supernum.